# What is best way to access element div > div[index] > div[index] in protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I have the following HTML code

```
<div id="parent">
    <div> <!-- First child div-->
        <div> <!-- First child div of first child-->
            <button>1st Button</button>
            <button>2nd button</button>
        </div>
        <div> <!-- Second child div of first child-->
           Some Other element
        </div>
    </div>
    <div> <!-- Second child div-->
        <div><!-- First child div of second child-->
            some other element
        </div>
        <div><!-- second child div of second child-->
            <button>3rd button</button>
            <button>4th button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To access direct child of parent div i used the function

```
getDirectChildDiv(position){
    return element.all(by.css('#parent > div')).get(position)
}
```

Similarly how to access again direct child of that child using above function 'getDirectChildDiv'

```
getDirectChildDivOfFirstChild(position){
    return this.getDirectChildDiv(0).all(' `?????` > div')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get the desired by using one function**

```
getXXX(position) {
   return element.all(by.css('#parent > div:nth-child(' + position + ') > div'))
}
```

**Or as your code by using two functions**

```
getDirectChildDiv(position){
    return element.all(by.css('#parent > div')).get(position)
}

getDirectChildDivOfFirstChild(position){
    return this.getDirectChildDiv(0).all('div')
}
```

Comment: Sorry to reply after long. I have updated the question, please revisit my question I have made my question clear. @yong